# Vim 7.2 hangs on startup, "killall vim" fixes it

Tags: vim

I just compiled vim 7.2 on a Linux server (in my user dir, since the server had vim 6 installed and I wanted to upgrade but do not have root privileges).

When I enter "vim", it hangs on startup without any response, but when I call "killall vim" from another ssh window, startup completes and vim seems to work fine after that. Why would that be, and how can I fix it?

Many thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 28):

Well, I found the answer:

```
:help -X
```

shows that Vim tries to connect to the X11 server on startup to get clipboard functionality and other stuff, which can lead to a "long startup time when running Vim in a terminal emulator and the connection to the X server is slow"

There are three ways to resolve this issue:

1. Starting Vim with "`vim -X`" disables this X11 communication
2. Calling "`unset DISPLAY`" also disables the X11 communication
3. If Vim is compiled without the "`+X11`" feature, this communication will not take place

I went for "`unset DISPLAY`" since I've been getting other strange error messages, and now vim starts all but instantly. I also tested the -X parameter, which resolved the problem as well (even with the DISPLAY parameter still set).

Comment: I added "unset DISPLAY" to my screenrc.

Comment: I've tried numbers 1 and 2, and they didn't work for me. Setting 'set mouse=' in .vimrc did the trick.

Comment: I added an alias in my .zshrc to
alias vim="/usr/bin/vim -X" 
this is all I needed because I do use the DISPLAY variable when using GUI apps on WSL

Answer (score 7):

`strace vim` will probably tell you what's hanging it.

Comment: i had the same problem, strace saved my day

Comment: Thanks! With `strace`, I saw it was getting stuck around uses of the `DISPLAY` environment variable and then realised it was set incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Another common reason for vim hanging at startup is when it is trying to access GPM (ie: custom fonts, etc). In my case, I was having the same symptoms, but it ended up being a mouse-related issue with GPM.

Putting the following (from: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/vim-freeze-at-startup-when-in-ssh-session-856606/) in my .vimrc fixed the hang-on-startup issue with VIM.

```
" This section is bigger in my .vimrc, this is just an excerpt.
if has('gui_running')
  " Mouse on GUI comes handy.
  set mouse=a
else
  set mouse=
endif
```

Hope this helps other readers that come this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Related to the mentioned case of vim hanging at startup when trying to access GPM, you can tell if this is the case using `strace`. First run vim in one terminal/console so that it hangs

```
vim
```

then go to another terminal, get the PID and strace it

```
$> pgrep vim                        
32502

$> strace -p 32502
Process 32502 attached - interrupt to quit
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/dev/gpmctl"...}, 13
```

So we have a GPM case. Just restart the GPM service and we are good to go

```
$> service gpm restart
Shutting down console mouse services:                      [  OK  ]
Starting console mouse services:                           [  OK  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strace vim` to find the error gave me this:

.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---

so removing `Vundle.vim` fixed the issue.